# getting variables from STRING url in php

Tags: php, url

If I have a url that looks like this, what's the best way to read the value

```
http://www.domain.com/compute?value=2838
```

I tried `parse_url()` but it gives me `value=2838` not `2838`

**Edit:** please note I'm talking about a string, not an actual url. I have the url stored in a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting vars from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413425/getting-vars-from-url)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `parse_url` and then `parse_str` on the query.

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.domain.com/compute?value=2838";
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$vars = array();
parse_str($query, $vars);
print_r($vars);
?>
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [value] => 2838
)
```

Answer (score 3):

For `http://www.domain.com/compute?value=2838` you would use `$_GET['value']` to return 2838

Answer (score 1):

```
$uri = parse_url($uri);
parse_str($uri['query'], $params = array());
```

Be careful if you use parse_str() without a second parameter. This may overwrite variables in your script!

Answer (score 0):

parse_str($url) will give you $value = 2838.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use GET method e.g

```
echo "value = ".$_GET['value'];
```